# How to remove an application that has been deleted but remains in the Status bar?

Tags: macos, finder, ios

I've recently deleted the Citrix Receiver app from my computer, but I've noticed that despite doing this (As well as deleting the plugin), my status bar has the Citrix roundel icon every time I boot up. I can't find a way to set it to not do that in the limited preferences menu I can open from it, but that is a bit besides the point. I want all traces of the application permanently removed, not just hidden from my view.

How can I remove this application from my status bar (And from my computer), clearly deleting the App itself from my Applications folder wasn't enough. But where is the rest persisting on my computer? I've tried searching through finder but nothing turned up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Citrix.com - [How to Uninstall Citrix Online Plug-in For Mac](https://www.citrix.com/blogs/2010/12/10/how-to-uninstall-citrix-online-plug-in-for-mac/)

This is the instructions for Online rather than Receiver. The process is identical for each, substituting the Receiver .dmg file
*(the Receiver instructions are in a pdf rather than online & can't be copy/pasted)*

> Citrix Online Plug-in (client) for Mac installs files into multiple
>   folders. Here is an easy way to uninstall:
>
> Download the installer from [Citrix download page](http://www.citrix.com/English/ss/downloads/results.asp?productID=186&c1=sot2755).
>
> Open the file and select Uninstall option.
>
> [image]

Comment: Nice, I didn't think of looking for an uninstaller. Typically most Apps don't have one. Thanks! Will accept answer when limit expires.

Comment: Welcome - I updated to include Online & Receiver - process is the same, but Online was easier to extract the info.